# How to improve this inequality?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to solve this problem. In a step of a proof that i'm finishing, i set

$$ y(t):= \int_{0}^{\delta} x^k e^{-ct x^4} dx. $$ Then, with this position, a such previous equation become

$$ y^{\prime}(t) = \frac{\delta^{k+1} e^{-ct x^4}}{4t} - \frac{k+1}{4} \frac{y(t)}{t} $$

So, in the next passage i would write
$$ y^{\prime}(t) = \frac{\delta^{k+1} e^{-ct x^4}}{4t} - \frac{k+1}{4} \frac{y(t)}{t} \leq -\frac{k+1}{4} \frac{y(t)}{t+1}, $$

in order to have

\begin{align}
\frac{y^{\prime}(t)}{y(t)} \leq -\frac{k+1}{4} \frac{1}{t+1}.
\end{align}

and then, by intregating, have the statement.
The problem is in the last inequlity here
$$ y^{\prime}(t) = \frac{\delta^{k+1} e^{-ct x^4}}{4t} - \frac{k+1}{4} \frac{y(t)}{t} \leq -\frac{k+1}{4} \frac{y(t)}{t+1}. $$

I justify it by saying that, taking $\delta $ sufficiently small, the inequlity is true. Other guys said me that, if $ \delta $ is small, then i would have problem with the definition of $ y(t). $

Could anyone help me understand how to proceed? Or give me a better inequlity in the line i mentioned before?

Note: Here $ t > 0, $ and $ k, c $ are some positive constants.

Comment: I don't understand your second line. If $y=y(t)$ then $y'=dy/dt = \int  d/dt ( \dots ) dx  $ i.e.
$$ y' = \int_0^\delta -c x^{k+4} e^{-ctx^4} dx $$
right?

Comment: No, with those position of $ y(t), $ then a previous expression (that I didn’ report) becomes $ y’(t) = \cdots$

Comment: The "such" confused me, sorry. Then what is the meaning of $x$ in the equation $y'=\dots$, if there is no integral? You didn't explain this at the bottom with the other variables $t,k,c$. I also don't know what your goal is.